# Unable to resample if the datetime has missing entries for a minute or more

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resampling

I am able to resample a dataframe which has two columns, LTP and TIMESTAMP.

I simple use this command: `resamp_df = resamp_df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('1T').ohlc()`

This works only if there is no missing data in the dataframe. I mean timeseries has to be continuous. Every minute entry must be present. Else it won't resample. For example, in the image below, data won't NOT resample because it has data missing for the minute 13:19

I wish to know if there is a way to resample such data which has a minute or more data entry missing.

Thanks in advance.

> [image: Blockquote]

Here is the excel csv data:

```
289.95  12/5/2019 13:18:00
289.8   12/5/2019 13:18:01
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:02
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:03
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:04
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:05
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:05
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:07
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:08
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:09
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:10
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:11
289.9   12/5/2019 13:18:11
289.85  12/5/2019 13:20:07
289.85  12/5/2019 13:20:08
289.85  12/5/2019 13:20:09
289.85  12/5/2019 13:20:10
289.9   12/5/2019 13:20:11
289.9   12/5/2019 13:20:12
289.9   12/5/2019 13:20:14
289.8   12/5/2019 13:20:15
289.8   12/5/2019 13:20:16
```

Comment: please dont post an image of the dataframe. paste it in here so ppl can copy it

Comment: @luigigi How? I have data in excel spreadsheet. How can I add it to the question?

Comment: 289.95 12/5/2019 13:18:00
289.8 12/5/2019 13:18:01
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:02
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:03
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:04
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:05
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:05
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:07
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:08
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:09
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:10
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:11
289.9 12/5/2019 13:18:11
289.85 12/5/2019 13:20:07
289.85 12/5/2019 13:20:08
289.85 12/5/2019 13:20:09
289.85 12/5/2019 13:20:10
289.9 12/5/2019 13:20:11
289.9 12/5/2019 13:20:12
289.9 12/5/2019 13:20:14
289.8 12/5/2019 13:20:15
289.8 12/5/2019 13:20:16

Comment: `df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('1min').ohlc()` is working fine for me

Comment: even with missing data? surprising.. it is not resampling at my end

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: it resamples till it hit the disconitunity.. after that, all values are NaN

Comment: Are you sure you are working with `datatime` dtype?

Comment: in the above case, it resampled data till 13:18

Comment: @jorijnsmit yes